# Switching from Linq-To-SQL to Entity Framework for WCF Data Services Issue with FK "Properties"

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-sql, entity-framework, data-conversion

So, In my old Linq-To-SQL I would write code like this

```
var tableItem = new Table
{
    Prop1 = var1
    Prop2 = var2,
    Prop3 = var3,
    ParentTableID = parentRecordID
};

db.Table.InsertOnSubmit(tableItem);
db.SubmitChanges();
```

After converting my working code from Linq-To-SQL to Entity Framework (v3.5) the `ParentTableID` property is no longer there and I'm at a loss as to how I can create this related child record.

I'm not sure what I should change for my entity framework version, besides the obvious call to `SaveChanges();` instead of `SubmitChanges()` :(

Comment: The solution at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/480872/entity-framework-setting-a-foreign-key-property/ has fixed my compiler errors, but I'm still working through some other stuff errors. I'll see what I find.

Comment: Agree with marc_s; EF4 is much more production-ready. Upgrade if at all possible.

Comment: This will require .NET4 -- correct?

Comment: @marc_s, you can easily find/set the IDs through the `EntityKey` property, if you care to, in 3.5 SP1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the solution here: [Entity Framework: Setting a Foreign Key Property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/480872/entity-framework-setting-a-foreign-key-property/1037910#1037910).

Answer (score 0):

For .NET 4, you can use FK associations.

For .NET 3.5 SP1 (I'm guessing at your property names; fix it if I guess wrong):

```
var tableItem = new Table
{
    Prop1 = var1
    Prop2 = var2,
    Prop3 = var3,
    ParentTable = db.Table.Where(t => Id == parentRecordID).First();
};

db.Table.AddObject(tableItem);
db.SaveChanges();
```